# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'knox'

Tags: solidity, metamask

I added the *Django-rest-Knox* into the requirement.txt then ran the *"docker-compose up"* command in my terminal. But, I got this error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Knox'". Any idea, why is that?

Comment: after pip install django-rest-knox you need to migrate : python manage.py migrate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install Knox module for Django. Use this command to do it:

```
pip install -U django-rest-knox
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and realized that I installed Django-rest-knox under virtual environment.